# Modify arnold render settings in python

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to modify the arnold common render settings of maya but I'm at the loss.

There is any function where I can call these arguments such as Image size presets, ratio and so on using python instead of MEL?

Sorry if someone already asked, but I've searched but with no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the render settings and point to the settings you want to change using Python?

Comment: Sure!  I wanna change this settings marked in red

http://s3.postimg.org/rz8emph6b/capt.png

Answer (score 1):

I solved it =)

Just in case someone needed

```
for setting in settingNames:
    print "defaultArnoldDriver.%s = %s" %( setting , cmds.getAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.%s" % setting  ) )
```

to know the settings names

and

```
cmds.setAttr ('defaultRenderGlobals.outFormatControl', 2 );
```

for the other rendering settings =)